# ad is not visible. not refreshing issue with admob in android fragments

Tags: java, android, admob, android-xml

Am using the following code. Every time on logcat am getting the dialogue ad is not visible. not refreshing. And the ad is not showing but the same thing is working fine when am using it with out the help of a fragments.

Somebody please tell me whats worng with my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
     <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                   >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 />

                <Button
             android:id="@+id/Button1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="3"
             android:paddingRight="5dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             />
     </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        />

                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView4"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:paddingRight="5dp"
                 />
                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                 android:paddingRight="10dp"
                 android:text=""
                 />
                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView5"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:paddingRight="5dp"
                 />
                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                 android:paddingRight="10dp"
                 />
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.xx.xx;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    ListView list;
    Lazyimg adapter;
    String name,imageurl,description,ingradiants,tduration;
    String[] mname,mimageurl;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    String ids,b1status;
    Button b1;
    private static Typeface typeFace = null;
    private static Typeface itypeFace = null;


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        AdView adView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        b1=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Button1);

        ids= getArguments().getString("ids");
        ids=ids.replace(" ", "%20");
        ids=ids.replace("-", "%27");

        initTypeFace(getActivity());
        iinitTypeFace(getActivity());
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click  
                GetData obj = new GetData();
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                        "Please wait...", true);
                TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                      String deviceIMEI = tManager.getDeviceId(); 
                String urls="cczczccxx/xxy.php?id="+ids+"&imei="+deviceIMEI+"&fav=jomin";
                obj.execute(urls);
            }
        }); 
        loadingPopup();

    }



    private void loadingPopup() {
        GetData obj = new GetData();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                "Loading recipe details...", true);
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              String deviceIMEI = tManager.getDeviceId(); 
        String urls="xxx/xxy.php?id="+ids+"&imei="+deviceIMEI;
        obj.execute(urls);

    }
     public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                BufferedReader reader =null;
                String data =null;

                try{

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    URI uri=new URI(params[0]);

                    HttpGet get =new HttpGet(uri);

                    HttpResponse response= client.execute(get);

                    InputStream stream=response.getEntity().getContent();

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                    StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    data = buffer.toString();

                    JSONObject fulldata = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray albumdata = (JSONArray) fulldata.get("data");
                    JSONObject  sobj = null;

                    name=""; imageurl=""; description=""; ingradiants=""; tduration=""; b1status="";

                    for(int j=0;j<albumdata.length();++j)
                    {
                    sobj= (JSONObject) albumdata.get(j);
                    b1status += (String)sobj.get("fav");
                    name += (String) sobj.get("name");
                    imageurl += (String) sobj.get("imageurl");
                    description += (String) sobj.get("description");
                    ingradiants += (String) sobj.get("ingradiants");
                    tduration += (String) sobj.get("tduration");
                    }

                    return "";

                }
                catch(URISyntaxException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(ClientProtocolException f){
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException g){
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                //
                }
                finally{
                    if(reader!=null){
                        try{
                            reader.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                if(result==null)
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setMessage("\n    Connection Error..!\n")
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        getActivity().finish();    
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoga, int which) {
                        try {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                        GetData obj = new GetData();
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                                "Loading recipe details...", true);
                        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getBaseContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                              String deviceIMEI = tManager.getDeviceId(); 
                        String urls="xxxxy.php?id="+ids+"&imei="+deviceIMEI;
                        obj.execute(urls);
                    }

                })
                .show();
                }
                else
                {

                mname = name.split("xstream");
                mimageurl = imageurl.split("xstream");

                if(b1status.equals(""))
                {
                    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favr);
                }
                else if(b1status.equals("f"))
                {
                    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favrg);
                }
                TextView ting=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                ting.setText("Ingredients");
                ting.setTypeface(typeFace);
                ting.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#210B61"));
                ting.setTextSize(25);

                TextView tpre=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                tpre.setText("\n\nDirections for Preparation");
                tpre.setTypeface(typeFace);
                tpre.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#210B61"));
                tpre.setTextSize(25);

                if(tduration.equals(""))
                {
                    TextView ttduration=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    ttduration.setText("READY IN : Depends");
                    ttduration.setTypeface(itypeFace);
                    ttduration.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
                    ttduration.setTextSize(20);
                }
                else
                {
                TextView ttduration=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                ttduration.setText("READY IN : "+tduration);
                ttduration.setTypeface(itypeFace);
                ttduration.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
                ttduration.setTextSize(20);
                }

                TextView tingradiants=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                ingradiants=ingradiants.replaceAll("<br>", "\n\n");
                ingradiants=ingradiants.replaceAll("&#34;", "\"");
                ingradiants=ingradiants.replaceAll("&#39;", "'");
                ingradiants=ingradiants.replaceAll("&#174;", " ");
                tingradiants.setText(ingradiants);
                tingradiants.setTypeface(typeFace);
                tingradiants.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tingradiants.setTextSize(20);


                TextView tdescription=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                description=description.replaceAll("<br>", "\n\n");
                description=description.replaceAll("&#34;", "\"");
                description=description.replaceAll("&#39;", "'");
                description=description.replaceAll("&#174;", " ");

                tdescription.setText(description);
                tdescription.setTypeface(itypeFace);
                tdescription.setTextSize(20);

                list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
                // Create custom adapter for listview
                adapter=new Lazyimg(getActivity(), mimageurl,mname);

                //Set adapter to listview
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                                //Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                //b.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }
        }
     public static void initTypeFace(Context context) {

                try {
                    typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Nexa_Light.otf");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
     public static void iinitTypeFace(Context context) {

         try {
             itypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "iowan.ttf");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

 }
}
```

Comment: any error my be come

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: have u check it on device or emulater

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar on device.

Comment: have u use any code in fragment

Comment: nothing problem check code ads is open on my device

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar _/\_

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as your AdView not actually being on screen. The AdView is contained within a ScrollView so there is no guarantee that it is actually on screen.

You have a complicated view hierarchy. Suggest you simplify it and move the AdView outside of your ScrollView.